# busyIndicator not showing in R shiny App

Tags: r, shiny, shinysky

I have a shiny app with a tabsetpanel which tabs are also subdivided in 2 tabs, and I wish to show a simple busyIndicator (default loading image) when shiny is busy loading data in one of the subtabs.

simplified code piece:

```
tabsetPanel(id = "tabs",
    tabPanel(value = 3, ("Tab3"),
           tabsetPanel(id = "subPanel3", position = "left",
                tabPanel(value = 9, ("View"), icon = icon("eye-open", lib = "glyphicon"),
                   busyIndicator(text = "Loading, please wait...", wait = 400), (...)
                   DT::dataTableOutput("lc")
```

I have used this feature before but this time it is not showing and I don't know why. Has anything been changed? I don't see any needed shinySky update.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar issue -- though I'm not sure my solution will solve your problem. Also, I'm probably too late to the party, but it might help others.

In my case, the `busyIndicator` was hidden behind the other output (table, plot, etc.). By moving the `busyIndicator` line below the `dataTableOutput` line, it becomes visible. That is, swap the two lines in the `tabPanel`:

```
tabsetPanel(id = "tabs",
    tabPanel(value = 3, ("Tab3"),
           tabsetPanel(id = "subPanel3", position = "left",
                tabPanel(value = 9, ("View"), icon = icon("eye-open", lib = "glyphicon"),
                   DT::dataTableOutput("lc")
                   busyIndicator(text = "Loading, please wait...", wait = 400)
```